# ASP.NET Core SignalR with jQuery

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have a project useing the asp.net SignalR which has jQuery.

In the client I can't add the .Net Core SignalR as a library or other external library.

In the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> The dependency on jQuery has been removed, however projects can still
>   use jQuery.

Is there a signalR for .net core with jquery?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't add the .Net Core SignalR as a library"? Is there an error when you try to add it or at runtime? There is nothing to stop you using jQuery in your project - it's just that the .Net Core SignalR library no longer depends on jQuery to work.

Comment: .net core is the backend part, you can use whatever you want in the front end

Comment: @strickt01 The implementation for the asp.net SignalR was to load the script from the backend, and at it to the doom, and from there call $.connection.hub.start() For the .NET core signalR, I have to create an instance for the hub,  signalR.HubConnectionBuilder(), wich requires the signalR library on client side. I am trying to use the jQuery for the implementation, without the library.